# How do I get the client id in a Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've set up a laravel app with client authentification. I send it my client id and client secret and it gives me a token. I'm able to log in to my laravel app, but I can't figure out how to get the id of the client that's been authorized.

I've seen hints to use `auth()->user()->Token()->getAttribute('client_id')` to get the client id, but since I'm only using clients there is no user and I get an error about trying to call Token() on a null object. `Auth::id()` also returned nothing. I grabbed the token from the header with `Request::header('Authorization')`, but it didn't match anything in the database.

Comment: Have you tried `Auth::user()->id`?

Comment: Yes, it tells me that Auth::user() is null. Which I suppose is expected since I don't have any users, just clients.

Comment: Did you use the `php artisan make:auth` command? Or have you written the client authentication from scratch?

Comment: What are you using for client Auth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using client credentials grant tokens, and the `CheckClientCredentials` middleware.

You can get this information from the bearer token, but it's not that straightforward. You would need to create a new PSR7 request with the token, and send it off to the oauth server to have it converted to readable data.

This is already done inside the `CheckClientCredentials` middleware provided by Passport. So, one way to do this would be to extend the `CheckClientCredentials` middleware and just manually set the needed fields on the request object from inside the middleware.

First, create `app/Http/Middleware/MyCheckClientCredentials.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials;

class MyCheckClientCredentials extends CheckClientCredentials
{
    /**
     * The Resource Server instance.
     *
     * @var \League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer
     */
    private $server;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  mixed  ...$scopes
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try {
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);

            // This is the custom line. Set an "oauth_client_id" field on the
            // request with the client id determined by the bearer token.
            $request['oauth_client_id'] = $psr->getAttribute('oauth_client_id');

        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Next, update your `app/Http/Kernel.php` to use your custom middleware instead of the build in Passport middleware:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'client' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyCheckClientCredentials::class,
];
```

Apply the middleware to your route as normal:

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
    // Should show "oauth_client_id" field.
    dd($request->all());
})->middleware('client');
```

If you don't want to do this inside a middleware, you can study how the Passport middleware works and reuse this code in some type of service if you'd like.

NB: all untested.

Comment: That ended up crashing on me on the line `$psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);`, so I just pulled all of CheckClientCredentials instead of extending it. It's working well now, thank you very much.

Comment: @Califer I see. I didn't see before, but evidently the `$server` property is defined as `private`, so it doesn't come over when extended. You just need to redefine the property in your child class. I have updated my answer to reflect this. But, glad you got it working either way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar in a logger middleware of mine:

```
.......................
    $user = $request->user();

    if($user) {
        // assume the authorization header exists, since the user is authenticated
        $header = $request->headers->get('authorization');

        if($header) { // authorization header is not set when testing via Passport::actingAs() 
            /**
             * Stolen from League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator#63 
             */

            // Get the actual jwt string from the header
            $jwt = trim(preg_replace('/^(?:\s+)?Bearer\s/', '', $header));

            // Parse the token from the string
            $token = (new Lcobucci\JWT\Parser())->parse($jwt);

            // Get the ID from the token
            $oauthClientId = $token->getClaim('aud');
        }
    }
.......................
```

Comment: This doesn't work as of now, as the Parser is an interface, and the actual implementation Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Parser takes additional parameters

Comment: Took a lot longer to break than I thought it would 